# mysql join basic question

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a pretty basic question that I imagine would require a join to pull off. However I am very new to mysql! Here is what I need to pull off:

I have 3 tables:

`Products`, `attributes`, and `products_to_attributes`

What I need to do is select the attributes which are associated to the product I want to query, based off the `products_to_attributes` table.

So lets say my product id=`1`, I need to grab all the rows in the attributes tables based off the `products_to_attributes` table which simply holds the pid to aid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM attributes a
INNER JOIN products_to_attributes pa ON a.aid = pa.aid
WHERE pa.pid = 1
```

Comment: this has me confused. what is a, and pa?

Comment: Aliases for the table, to not have to type the entire tablename each time. The syntax is `SELECT a.ID from attributes AS a`, but you can omit the `AS`.

Comment: @Greg, and if you want to access the columns inside `products` just add another `INNER JOIN products p ON (pa.pid = p.pid)` after the first join criterion.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM attributes a, products_to_attributes  b
WHERE a.aid = b.aid
AND b.pid = 1
```

it's basically the same answer as [tofutim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/339843/tofutim), but without using the `INNER JOIN` syntax.

Comment: The INNER JOIN syntax is preferred over the ANSI-89 style.

Comment: And using implicit `where` join will get you downvotes on SO.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins  i donno, it feels that it's somewhat of a preference

Comment: it is **not** something of a preference. Implicit `where` joins are confusing and error-prone because you do not separate the `join` conditions from the filters in the `where` condition. On big joins with multiple tables and complex join criteria this quickly gets out of hand.